# jquery nth-child() not working

Tags: jquery, html

I need some help regarding jquery.
This is HTML code

```
<div id="outerDiv">
<div id="firstInnerDiv">
    First Inner Div
</div>

<label class="label1">First Label</label><br/>

<div id="secondInnerDiv">
    Second Inner Div
</div>

<label class="label2">Second Label</label>
</div>

<label class="label2">Third Label</label>
```

and this is jquery code

```
    $("‪#‎outerDiv‬ div:nth-child(1)").insertAfter("label:nth-child(4)");
    $("#outerDiv label:nth-child(1)").insertAfter("div:nth-child(4)");
```

The output of the above code is :
First Inner Div
First Label
Second Inner Div
Second Label
Third Label

I want a new sequence which should be like this :

Second Inner Div
Second Label
First Inner Div
First Label
Third Label

Comment: which browser do you use? The `nth-child` attribute is not support below IE8.

Comment: I am using chrome but for this code I have to make sure it runs on every browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems

1. there are some hidden characters in the script in your question (*perhaps it is just the copy/paste*)
2. you need to target the 5 element in the `insertAfter` since there is a `<br>` that also counts

```js
$("#outerDiv div:nth-child(1)").insertAfter('label:nth-child(5)');
$("#outerDiv label:nth-child(1)").insertAfter('div:nth-child(5)');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="outerDiv">
    <div id="firstInnerDiv">First Inner Div</div>
    <label class="label1">First Label</label>
    <br/>
    <div id="secondInnerDiv">Second Inner Div</div>
    <label class="label2">Second Label</label>
</div>
<label class="label2">Third Label</label>
```

Answer (score 4):

[Quoting jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/):

> The `:nth-child(n)` pseudo-class is easily confused with `:eq(n)`, even
>   though the two can result in dramatically different matched elements.
>   With `:nth-child(n)`, all children are counted, regardless of what they
>   are, and the specified element is selected only if it matches the
>   selector attached to the pseudo-class.

So, when you use a selector like `label:nth-child(1)`, you're saying "all `label` elements that are the first child of their parent," **not** "all the first `label` elements." If there's something else, like a `div`, that's the first child, `label:nth-child(1)` matches nothing.

It may be more natural for you to use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), which lets you specify an index in the matched set. Or, you could use [`:nth-of-type`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/), which works closer to how I think you assumed `:nth-child` did.

Comment: What my logic is that.....in the first line I have moved the first child of the "outerDiv" which is also a div after the fourth child...so it no longer remains the first child and then the label with the class "label1" becomes the first child.

Comment: and after that that label is moved after the fourth child which is again a div tag that was moved earlier

Comment: I notice the specific numbers in the `nth-child` selectors have changed since your original posting. Are they accurate now?